# Ruby koans repository down

Tags: ruby, git, github, zip

Does anyone have a link to the  zip? The github repository seems to be down: https://github.com/neo/ruby_koans/blob/master/download/rubykoans.zip?raw=true

And I really want to start learning ruby by doing those tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I can see, the repo you are trying to find either was deleted or was made private.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I hoped that somebody here had the zip file for the ruby koan,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are copies of the `rubykoans.zip` in the links below:

- https://github.com/MakeSchool-17/ruby-koans-cmaher92/tree/master/download
- https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/tree/master/download

You'll should also find it in many of the forks of this repository on GitHub:
https://libraries.io/github/neo/ruby_koans/forks?page=2